# Tense used with statistics

Tags: present-tense, simple-past, tenses

I would like to place a statistics in front of the sentence, followed by the agency that has reported it. The findings and reports were done many years ago. Which of the two is correct and why?

> 1. Nearly 10 million Americans accept..., the U. S. Office of Public Affairs reports.
> 2. Nearly 10 million Americans accept..., the U. S. Office of Public Affairs reported.

Likewise, should it be "Americans accept" or "Americans accepted"?

Comment: The correct form of constructing these sentences depends on the recommended/ applicable style in the context. Ask also on writersSE. Check the style guide applicable to your document. Grammatically it is possible to construct the sentences either way.

Comment: Well, I'm writing an academic paper, specifically a Position Paper if it does affect the way that the sentence should be structured.

Comment: It can be assumed from the context that the report has not been superseded so far, and the data is **currently valid**. There appears to be no reason to use the past tense in the absence of any other factor.

Comment: Style guides vary. MLA, widely used in US humanities departments, embraces the present tense for your 'reports'; APA, used in social sciences, deprecates it. As to *accept/accepted*, that will depend on the reference time of your data.

Comment: @Kris I thank you for your comment! Am I right to say that the correct sentence should then be "Nearly 10 million Americans **accept** ...., the U.S. Office of Public Affairs **reports**.

Comment: @StoneyB Could you please explain what you meant by depending on the reference time of my data?

Comment: Karen, see @Fortiter's response. 'Speech time' is the time at which you write or are read ('now'); 'Event time' is the time at which what you are writing about occurred (the time of the data); and 'Reference time' is the particular temporal standpoint in which you locate your statement - in your case, the time at which the data were reported.

Comment: You are obviously quoting the source in support of something you state in the paper. Yes, (also, to assert that the data is relevant and current), you may say "Nearly 10 million Americans **accept** ..., the U.S. Office of Public Affairs **reports**."

Answer (score 5):

If the findings were reported "many years ago" then that should be made explicit in your Position Paper.

Once the date is included in the sentence, then both "report" and "accept" will be forced into the past tense.

Failure to do so represents an implicit claim (by you) that the situation is unchanged since the original report. Such a claim probably requires justification.

Comment: +1 APA takes the position that *all* such data, having been published before the time of writing, must be cast in the past tense. MLA is followed primarily by writers on works which 'endure' into the present, and is accordingly less strict.

Answer (score 0):

From the perspective of content and rigour, this depends a bit on discipline (eg MLA for humanities vs APA for social sciences), as well as on the reasonableness of the extrapolation from **many** years ago till now, and your willingness to be accountable for the extrapolation. If you intend to imply that the results are still valid, use 'accept'; if you don't want to be responsible for that extrapolation, 'accepted' would be better.

From a stylistic perspective, it can seem pedantic and infelicitous to switch tenses to maintain complete accuracy, depending on the surrounding text and its style. Nonetheless, rigour of thought and expression in many academic contexts are more important than mellifluous readability.